# How to tell if 2 arrays share the same element

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, element

So this is a simpler form of my problem.
Lets say I have 2 arrays. A= {1,2} and B={2,4,6}.
If A and B share an element then delete that element from B. 
I know you can loop through and compare each element in A to each element in B, but there's got to be a better way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your arrays are sorted (or you can sort the arrays), you can then work through both arrays simultaneously. Starting at the beginning of both arrays and going until you would advance one of the pointers beyond the end of its respective array:

- If a < b then advance the a pointer
- If a = b then delete the element at b
- If a > b then advance the b pointer

Answer (score 3):

You have to write code, but it doesn't have to be a brute-force doubly nested loop and you don't have to do any messy removal of individual elements from arrays.

If you add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (from the Tools menu in the VBE), you can use a Dictionary object to make this easier. It has methods for 'Exists', 'Remove', and 'Keys'. So you could loop through B and add the elements as keys in the Dictionary, and then loop through A, checking to see if those elements exist, and if so, removing them.

As pseudocode:

```
for each elem in b
    dict(elem)=0 
next elem

for each elem in a
    if dict.exists(elem)
        dict.remove(elem)
    end if
next elem

return dict.keys
```

The above approach also removes duplicates from B if there are any.

If you know your arrays don't have error values as elements, you can also use MATCH (and in VBA 'Application.Match' or 'Application.WorksheetFunction.Match'). Doing something like

```
=MATCH({2,4,6},{1,2},0)
```

will return {2,#N/A,#N/A}. Any position with #N/A is the position of an element of B that wasn't in A. If you do the match in the worksheet, you can then drag a formula like

```
=IF(ISNA(cell of match),corresponding cell of B,NA())
```

and then filter out the #N/As from that. In VBA, you could do (more pseudocode):

```
matches=application.match(b,a,0) 

for each elem in matches
    if iserror(elem)
        add corresponding element of b to result
    end
next elem

redim result to new smaller size

return result
```

Of course, then you have to worry about array starting bounds, etc.

Comment: Hey, so I started playing around with dictionary objects, I did not know vba could use them. This is by far the coolest solution; however, I work in an office and it's a bit impractical to get everyone to enable "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". Just wanted to recognize your answer even though I didn't choose it as my 'selected answer'

Comment: Whatever works! FWIW, I think that if your colleagues open an Excel file that you created that had the reference set, then it will work just fine without them having to do anything. The Scripting Runtime is pretty much always there in Windows without doing anything special.

Answer (score 1):

**A completed and explained VBA solution based on jtolle's pseudo code**

```
    Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim a, b: a = Array(1, 2): b = Array(2, 4, 6)
    Debug.Print "Array b: {" & Join(b, ",") & "}";  ' show original array b
    
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'remove duplicates from b via Application.Index()
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    b = getUniques(a, b)                            ' << help function getUniques()
    
    Debug.Print " ~~> {" & Join(b, ",") & "}"       ' Array b: {2,4,6} ~~> {4,6}
    End Sub
```

**Help function `getUniques()` via 1-line `Application.Match()`**

//**Edit** *2020-07-24 corrected array boundaries due to @jtolle 's comment:*

```
    Function getUniques(a, b)
    'Purpose: get 1-based items of array b not matching with array a items
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'a) match array b items against array a
    '   results in a 1-based array {2,#N/A,#N/A}, where
    '   the 1st numeric element of b equalling 2 indicates to be the 2nd item of b and
    '   error elements indicate unique items in b with no duplicate in b
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim matches: matches = Application.Match(b, a, 0)   ' results in 1-based array with b dimensions
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'b) get 1-based unique items in array b
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long                           ' counters
    For i = 1 To UBound(matches)                        ' loop through matches
        If IsError(matches(i)) Then                     ' no match #N/A indicates unique item in b
            ii = ii + 1                                 ' increment new counter
            ''matches(ii) = b(i - IIf(LBound(b), 0, 1)) ' OP: get b items to maintain
              matches(ii) = b(i + LBound(b) - 1)        ' edited: get b items to maintain

        End If
    Next i
    ''ReDim Preserve matches(LBound(b) To ii - IIf(LBound(b), 0, 1)) ' OP: reduce to needed size and original boundaries
    ReDim Preserve matches(LBound(b) To ii + LBound(b) - 1) ' edited; reduce to needed size and original boundaries

    getUniques = matches                                ' return function result

    End Function
```

Comment: It's nice to see an old answer get some new input! Your code is a good reminder of how wary you have to be of array indices in VBA though. As crazy as it seems, some pathological caller might pass you an array that starts at index -42. So I think you'd need to tweak this a little to prevent bugs. (Your IIf seems to assume a lower bound of zero or one only.)

Comment: Having the same ideas in mind, I enjoyed very much finalizing your helpful code outline (upvoted btw)
... and yes, I appreciate your feedback to insist in bug prevention, 
especially regarding array bounds that might differ from the ones used normally. - @jtolle

Answer (score 0):

No there is not I think. You have to loop through.

Answer (score 0):

If values inside a array are unique for its array, you could make the array indexes the actual values, allowing you to seek directly to its index, instead of scanning the entire array.

Start with the array that has fewer elements, and i assume you are wanting to do excel/VB? I made a picture to illustrate the idea.

http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/1503/hackmap.jpg

Instead of having two nested loops, you have one loop, and it only iterates as many times as the smallest array.